# Using SBT, how can I package multiple war files from my code?

Tags: sbt

I would like my project to package multiple war files where I selectively include and exclude both code and resources. I would like to avoid splitting the project into more than one. The resources are not shared, the code (some of it) is.

Comment: I'm seriously considering using submodules for this one, it means I have to separate the sources a bit, but its really a more more elegant solution.